# Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator using a sum function with an imbedded datediff in a case statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to sum the total number of rows that have a '2' as the difference between col1 and col2. But when I use the below query, I get the "operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator".

I am not sure if this matters but here are some of the facts;

- col1 data type is datetime
- col2 data type is datetime
- col3 data type is datetime

Query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(day,_col1,_col2) = '0' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) day0
    FROM dbo1
    WHERE  year(_col3) between year(getdate())-'1' and year(getdate()) 
    AND _col1 is not null
    AND _col2 is not null
```

Comment: Remove 's, those are for strings and you're supposed to be using numbers. Also, you should use proper dates as search criteria and not compare year(date)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(day,_col1,_col2) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) day0
FROM    dbo1
WHERE   _col3   >= dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
and     _col3   <  dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0)
AND     _col1 is not null
AND     _col2 is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You use chars as a argument for the sum method.
why u didn't use the NUMBER!?
try this:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(day,_col1,_col2) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) day0
FROM dbo1
WHERE  year(_col3) between year(getdate())-1 and year(getdate()) 
AND _col1 is not null
AND _col2 is not null
```